# Bigquery event streaming - error 400

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I've got the following code set up:

```
def send_to_bq(bigquery, events, table_id):
    try:    
        data = {}
        data['rows'] = []
        data['skipInvalidRows'] = True # don't drop the entire batch if there's a bad record
        data['ignoreUnknownValues'] = True # ignore unknown fields

        for event in events:
            row = {
                'json': event,
                # Generate a unique id for each row so retries don't accidentally
                # duplicate insert
                'insertId': str(uuid.uuid4()),
            }
            data['rows'].append(row)
        if len(data['rows']) > 0:
            #print "request: " + json.dumps(data)            
            return bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(
                projectId=config['FUNTOMIC_PROJECTID'],
                datasetId=config['DATASET_ID'],
                tableId=table_id,
                body=data).execute(num_retries=int(config['CHUNK_RETRIES']))
        else:
            return 'Empty Event'
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
```

I'm tailing a log file and sending data to BQ. Every few iterations, randomly, the following exception will be thrown:

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/PROJECT_ID/datasets/DATASET_ID/tables/TABLE_ID/insertAll?alt=json returned "Parse Error">
```

Sometimes it could be a few times a day, sometimes it's every few seconds.
I have no idea what's going on, and I couldn't find anything in the BQ streaming docs.

I'm trying to understand if this happens on one of the retries (which I can then safely ignore) - a server error, or if this is only printed ever the retires have been exhausted (in which case I might lose events).

Thanks!

**Edit 1**
Changed my chunk size to 1, and printed such an event. The event is a valid JSON. Verified in BQ that it did NOT make it in.

```
{"is_synced": "False", "domain": "kiziland", "server_time": "1457116902", "event_type": "creature_bought", "ip": "151.62.108.127", "partial_data": "True", "agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Android; U; it-IT) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/19.0", "currency": "coins", "elapsed_play_time": "43536", "received_at": "1457116902893", "is_converted": "False", "city": "Trento", "uuid": "tZkUiABW6J5t", "coins_left": 266057442087380840000, "platform": "Android", "is_in_kizi_app": "False", "advertising_id": "f3cb67f6-c631-4a63-bd20-824ca8317eda", "creature_level": "39", "game_version": "1.1.11", "is_in_kizi_mobile_web": "False", "index": "mobile_games", "price": "1.15280492432e+21", "stars_left": "315", "current_max_creature": "49", "event_stream_time": 1457257312.162035, "day": "2016-03-04", "sourcetype": "mobile_events", "original_version": "1.1.11", "is_native": "True", "country": "IT", "install_date": "1453487933", "session_id": "FoKr8DwFAtikNc0X2X0P", "_time": "1457116902", "game_ops_version": "0.7.5", "host_type": "android_native_app", "is_in_kizi_web": "False"}
```

**Edit 2 - Solution**
Apparently when I was converting my python dictionary into a json event (need special handling for some types) I was not taking care of "long" types. They were the cause of the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like BigQuery cannot parse the body of request, due to invalid characters in your payload request.

If you try to validate it [1] you will see that this is an invalid JSON. It looks like the issue is the “agent” where invalid characters are found.

This is the agent provided:

```
"agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Android; U; it-IT) AppleWebKit/533.19.4
(KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/19.0"
```

As you can see, there is a newline after AppleWebKit/533.19.4 that you either need to remove or encode as follows:

```
“agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Android; U; it-IT) AppleWebKit/533.19.4\n(KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/19.0”
```

[1] http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did what you suggested, and edited my original post with a sample. I see nothing wrong with the event though...

Comment: @GilAdirim - yep, the json itself looks valid. how about the schema which you provide when you stream? can you publish it too please?

Comment: As you can see from the function above, I'm streaming, so I'm not supplying a schema. I'm also using skipInvalidRows & ignoreUnknownValues to avoid errors during insertion that are schema related.
I would post the schema itself, but it's a very sparse schema which consists of over 1K columns :)

Comment: @GilAdirim, I have updated my answer, please review.

Comment: That's not the agent from my example. Regardless, we added a "strip()" function to remove whitespace chars, and we are still getting the errors.